# two fields in one input form in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react application with two fields - one for email and one for password. Currently when I type something in email field, the password field also is populated. I want to separate those fields and when the user types email and password and hits "login", he should see both values, currently he sees one. Here's my code snippet:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('email: ' + this.state.value);
    alert('password: + ?');
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          email:
          <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
          password:
          <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Do you have any hints what is wrong in my code? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('email: ' + this.state.email);
    alert('password: + this.state.password);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          email:
          <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={e=>this.handleChange(e)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          password:
          <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={e=>this.handleChange(e)} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

You are assigning both of them to value and hence you don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are trying to have same state for two fields that's why your getting the same value.You should have two separate state values for two fields.

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {email: '',password: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('email: ' + this.state.email);
    alert('password: + ?');
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          email:
          <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
          password:
          <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two states, one for the email and one for the password and then you  can do something like this on you handleChange function:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {email: '', password: ''};

 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
 this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

After that you just need to change the input fields to use that piece of state:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```